# Get all error messages returned when I only want 1

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate a Mortgage Month field that is going to validate if the input is (Must be present. Must be numeric. Must be equal to the current month or 1 month greater than current month. Allowable values: 01 thru 12 inclusive). My validation seems to be working, although when I test to evaluate if the field is empty it shows every error message when i just want the one that says it is empty. How would I do this? Thank you.

my Javascript function:

```
function valMortMonth(errMessages){
var month = document.getElementById("mortMonth").value;
if (month.length === 0) {
errMessages += "<li>Mortgage Month can't be left empty</li>";
}

var monthValue = parseInt(month);

if (isNaN(monthValue)) {
errMessages += "<li>Mortgage Month must be numeric</li>";
}

var month = (new Date()).getMonth() + 1;

if (monthValue < 1 || monthValue> 12) {
errMessages += "<li>Mortgage Month must be between month 1 to 12</li>" ;
}

if (!(monthValue === month || monthValue === month + 1)) {
errMessages += "<li>Month must be equal to current month or 1 greater</li>";
}
return errMessages;
}
```

HTML:

```
<label class="label"> Month </label>

      <input type="text" name="mortMonth" id="mortMonth" size="4"   maxlength="2" >
```

output now for when field is left empty:

```
Mortgage Month must be numeric
Mortgage Month must be equal to current month or 1 month greater
```

Answer (score 0):

If you JUST want the one message, then simply add a return inside the `if` condition for that message, like so:

```
  if (month.length === 0) {
    errMessages += "<li>Mortgage Month can't be left empty</li>";
    return errMessages;
  }
```

You could add this to EACH `if` condition, if desired, if you truly only ever wanted one at a time.

Comment: so i would add that to the end of every error message?

Comment: Yes, if you want ONLY ever one message to display.  That is correct.

Comment: I've added the returns as suggested and it works. The only thing is it still skips the error that should say it is empty and goes straight to the is not numeric error message. I have no idea why this is happening....as the logic seems correct

Comment: In my testing, it worked.  However, if there's ONE empty space in there, it won't work.  I'd suggest changing it to more like `if (month.length === 0 || ! month.trim()) {....`

Comment: Also, if this is helpful, please upvote the answer (click the "up" arrow by the score)